# I Have some model i dont wanna insert manual or auto the @Id I just want to ingore it from insert ? Java

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Id
@Column(name="ROWID", insertable=false)
private String rowId;
@Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
private Integer clientId;
@Column(name="ACCT_NO")
private String acctNo;
@Column(name="ACCT_CIF_NO")
private String acctCifNo;
@Column(name="ACCT_TYPE")
private String acctType;
@Column(name="ACCT_CUR")
private String acctCur;
@Column(name="ACCT_STATUS")
private Integer acctStatus;
@Column(name="ACCT_MAX_TRX_AMOUNT")
private Long acctMaxTrxAmount;
@Column(name="ACCT_MAX_TRX_DAILY")
private Long acctMaxTrxDaily;
@Column(name="ACCT_NAME")
private String acctName;
@Column(name="CTL_CREATE_DTM")
private Date ctlCreateDtm;
@Column(name="CTL_CREATE_BY")
private String ctlCreateBy;
@Column(name="CTL_UPDATE_DTM")
private Date ctlUpdateDtm;
@Column(name="CTL_UPDATE_BY")
private String ctlUpdateBy;
```

I Have model and i want to use jpa repository for insert use this model but I dont want insert the rowId because its genarated from Oracle database so I want to skip it, it is possible ?

the service is just like this

```
@Override
public TEmasUsers create(TEmasUsers entity) {
    return emasUsersDao.save(entity);
}
```

[the table from database and no rowid on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgEng.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @GeneratedValue on you rowId column

```
@Id
@Column(name="ROWID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String rowId;
```

Comment: i have try it and error java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call

Comment: the Hibernate: insert into t_mir_client_accounts (rowid, acct_cif_no, acct_cur, acct_max_trx_amount, acct_max_trx_daily, acct_name, acct_no, acct_status, acct_type, client_id, ctl_create_by, ctl_create_dtm, ctl_update_by, ctl_update_dtm) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
I cant insert rowId by Default in value

Comment: @YhogiAndianggara could you provide full code example with your insertion?

Comment: it just normal insert, I user save from jpa

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long rowId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is the easiest way to achieve this. IDENTITY indicates that database IDENTITY columns will be used for primary key value generation.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ROWID")
private String rowId;
```

But, this is not the only change you might need to do. Your `ROWID` column must be some kind of auto-incrementable in your database.

In Oracle IDENTITY is supported from [version 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109) and looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    c1 NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, // this line
    c2 VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

So, I would also change `private String rowId;` to `private Long rowId;` if you want this to work with Oracle DB and only after that when you persist, auto-generated value will be inserted to that column.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ROWID")
private Long rowId;
```

Some details are missing, so let's imagine you have some repository:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<YourEntity, String> {}
```

When you want to persist something to DB you would do something like this:

```
...
YourEntity entity = new YourEntity();
// YOU DON'T SET rowId ! Remain it null
entity.setClientId(123);
entity.setAcctNo("123456");

// set all the other fields
...
```

And at some place, you would call:

```
...    
YourEntity persisted = someRepository.save(entity);
...
```

Once you persisted, this `persisted` will have `rowId` (in general, a field with @Id annotation) not `null` but with some value that is generated and set to that field.

Comment: when i user identity the hibernate query show loke this Hibernate: insert into t_mir_client_accounts (rowid, acct_cif_no, acct_cur, acct_max_trx_amount, acct_max_trx_daily, acct_name, acct_no, acct_status, acct_type, client_id, ctl_create_by, ctl_create_dtm, ctl_update_by, ctl_update_dtm) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: This row id is not in my table, this is from oracle maybe, and i cant insert it.

Comment: Wait i get it, ill try it 1st

Comment: you need to provide more details of how you do that insert - your repository, service or whatever you have there :) Maybe IDENTITY is not the right way for your particular case.

Comment: i just dont wanna insert row id ant let the database do it

Comment: How do you insert? Do you create entity like in my example or you have some SQL executed? Please add all these details to your question. Some information about ROWID column in a database would be also helpful. Maybe this column is not id (primary key) at all.

Comment: Yes i create an entity not use sql query.
in the table does have rowid column the row id is from oracle database, every row has rowid.
my table does'nt have primary key so I use ROWID for the primary key, but row id generated it self from oracle data base for each row i insert

Comment: @YhogiAndianggara I'm having a similar problem. Is there any progress on this issue? I'm using auto-ddl=create and haven't been able to generate a DDL like that "NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY"